# MVC submit button is always submitting the first record details on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I have a foreach loop in MVC page. like below. But, when I am submitting the form using submit button, it is always submitting the first record. Unable to understand why it is doing that way. Appreciate the help.

```html
@model IEnumerable<DeployModel>
 
 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Dep", FormMethod.Post))
{
     
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
               
                <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body" style="overflow-y: auto">
              
                    
                    @if (Model != null && Model.Any())
                    {
                         
                        <div>

                            <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                <th>
                                    S1 Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    S2 Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Old Version
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    New Version
                                </th>
                                
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                                
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(o => item.S1)
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(o => item.S2)
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(o => item.OldVersion)
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(o => item.NewVersion)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(o => item.Status)
                                            </td>

                                           
                                            <td>
                                               
                                          <button name="SubmitButton" class="btn action-btn" type="submit" > Submit                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                             
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
               
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

}
```

My Controller action looks like as, but it is always receiving first record irrespective of button click.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DeployModel deployModel)
{
   //TODO code
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You have to give them a diffrent `name` for it to work

Comment: Where I have to give different names? Could you please elaborate little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. The first is that `Html.DisplayFor` will just write the display string for the selected property's value with nothing telling the browser that it is form data to be submitted. The other is that all of your submit buttons are for the same form. There are a few ways to solve these problems. The one I would suggest is to create a separate form for each instance of `DeployModel`, and create hidden inputs for each property you are expecting to receive upon submission of the form:

```cs
// inside your foreach loop
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Dep", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="S1" value="@item.S1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="S2" value="@item.S2" />
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Also please note that if you use this method you should remove the outer form - you don't want nested forms!

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a diffrent Name for each input.

exmaple

```
@Html.DisplayFor(o => item.S1, new { name = "input1" })
```